# use correctly tags in phpdocumentator2

Tags: php, tags, phpdoc

I start to use Phpdocumentator2 (http://phpdoc.org/)
And I don't understand Why  when I wrote

```
/**
 @param STRING $url_p URL du WSDL
*/ 
public function  TestPHPdoc($url_p)
{
    echo('yes');

}
```

Phpdocumentator create correctly documentation like this
TestPHPdoc(STRING $url_p)

Parameters
STRING  $url_p

URL du WSDL
but when i wrote (correct way of write recommended by phpdoc)

```
/**
* @param STRING $url_p URL du WSDL
*/ 
public function  TestPHPdoc($url_p)
{
    echo('yes');

}
```

the documentation generated is ugly like this:

TestPHPdoc( $url_p)

- @param STRING $url_p URL du WSDL
  Parameters
  $url_p

(of course when write some of comment dedicated for  documentation , it's worse)

How can I solve this

more information
I use wamp on Windows , composer to install Phpdocumentator2 
and this ligne (on powershell) to generate documentation

```
C:\wamp\www\phpdoc\vendor\bin\phpdoc.php.bat -d C:\wamp\www\phpdoc\vendor\bin\source -t C:\wamp\www\phpdoc\vendor\bin\destination
```

yes I know its not the beautiful way to do it (generate directly on the script repository : but it's for test)

Comment: Used both your examples with phpDoc2... they produce the same output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: The problem just encoding of carriage return...